# Using one IP address to point to another changeable IP address

Tags: dns, ip

What I am trying to do is set up an IP address that I can give my customers that will allow me to redirect to another server's IP. The goal is to only have to change the customer's DNS information once but allow me to move to a different server whenever needed. For example, right now all of our sites are on Flywheel servers but in the future, I am thinking about moving to WP Engine or possibly even spinning up my own DigitalOcean server.

I have looked into a floating IP address from DigitalOcean but from what I can tell I would be locked into a single DigitalOcean data center. I really am looking for a solution that would keep me free and not tied down to a single provider.

Cloud Flares is interesting but its a name server solution, and I can't change every customer's name server as quite a few have complex setups that their IT companies manage.

I am not sure what the correct terminology for a process like this, so even pointing me in the direction of the correct thing to google would be most helpful.

Comment: Usually, one would advise customers to create CNAME record in their DNS which would just point to a name that you control, e.g `customer1.example.com  CNAME cheech-app.example.org`. After that, you just need to modify your DNS entry for `cheech-app.example.org` to point to new correct IP address

Comment: What about using a proxy? It seems like cloud flare sets up some sort of proxy so they don't expose your server's IP address. How is that done?

Comment: Also, If I am remembering right you can't use a CNAME for the root domain. I don't want my clients to have to use a subdomain.